# Glass material is smudgy and doesn't look like glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, glass

I downloaded [this 3D model of a glass vase](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-venini-ritagli-3d-model/843870?fbclid=IwAR3rU39QNgJ5SEXVHGDA5ybxVUqeBr-3KcKNuIRg_A2cgBK98PTgGJj-ViA) and I tried fixing the material in Blender using Cycles as my rendering engine but it looks so different in comparison to the material preview. See screenshots below:

[image][image]

Can anyone figure out why this is happening? If anyone can help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it. Been stuck on this for so long already and I'm getting frustrated. I've tried almost everything but nothing seems to work (such as putting roughness to 0, transmission to 1, using glass bdsf, etc)

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). If I may, what *exactly* doesn't look right to you? This looks more like lighting issue. Your viewport also seems to be heavily denoised, destroying details.

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi! If you visit this [link](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-venini-ritagli-3d-model/843870?fbclid=IwAR3rU39QNgJ5SEXVHGDA5ybxVUqeBr-3KcKNuIRg_A2cgBK98PTgGJj-ViA), you should see an image of how the glass should look like. I was wondering why the glass doesn't look as transparent and as light colored as the material preview. I actually tried adding a nearby light source to see if it was a lighting issue but the object still looked the same. :( i turned off denoising in my viewport right now to see if anything changes

Comment: @moonboots hi! are you referring to the blender file or just the obj file? :)

Comment: please share the blender file

Comment: @moonboots here you go! https://drive.google.com/file/d/133BvoWJG7k_hXvZZ6XoTSSCV8KTxPg3k/view?usp=sharing

hopefully all the external files were also packed there. let me know if theres any issues

Comment: in my opinion it looks like it is supposed to, you have several layers of meshes so it tends to make the material more opaque, but if you're not satisfied maybe use another set of nodes in order to give more transparency?

Comment: @moonboots alright! thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Some things that could help:

- To brighten shadows inside the glass, add more *Transmission* bounces
- For shooting glass (and other shiny objects), use high-contrast lighting
- Denoiser still needs a lot of samples to avoid artifacts and smudges

<sup>3-4 lights, HDRI environment, 1000 Render Samples + Denoiser</sup>
[image]
[image]

Related:
[How to make this glass more realistic?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26805/78972)
[How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2558/78972)

Comment: whoa this looks amazing and just how i wanted it to look like! LOL. but anyways, noted on all these and everything makes so much more sense now. thank you both so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Keep the questions coming and good luck with your project.

Comment: I do have one more question! Would you know any free programs or websites that can covert a .max file so I can import it in Blender? :) been looking everywhere but haven't had any luck. I'm a Mac user and apparently it's not available to use for Mac

Comment: Hey :). I don't know of any, since I'm not a max user. Related: [Can I import a .max file into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14808/78972)

Comment: Darn, alright! Thank you so much anyway. Have a good week :)

Comment: No problem, you too :)